# Get Pusher connected status real time

Tags: laravel, connection, pusher

I use Pusher.com to set up real time notification.
I rather use it for real time table sync.

But sometimes, it doesn't work well due to connection issue.
So I want to check if pusher connect is active or not.
I'm using Laravel for this system and 
I displayed the status with icon(Green and red icon).

Here is the code what I written in blade.php file

```
    var pusher = new Pusher('dfgfg', {
                cluster: 'us3',
                encrypted: true
            });

            pusher.connection.bind('connected', function() {
                $('#pusheron').css('display','flex');
                $('#pusheroff').css('display','none');
            });
            pusher.connection.bind('error', function() {
                $('#pusheron').css('display','none');
                $('#pusheroff').css('display','flex');
            });
```

This is what I've done now.
But it sometimes doesn't work correctly.
I would be glad if someone teach me other way to get pusher connection status in real time.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Pusher emits events when the connection state changes. You can use this to detect changes in real time and update the status display.

```
pusher.connection.bind('state_change', function(states) {
  // states = {previous: 'oldState', current: 'newState'}
  $('div#status').text("Channels current state is " + states.current);
});
```

See https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/connection#connection-states.

Comment: Thank you @doydoy for your reply.
I just wanted to get connection or disconnection status.
It seems working in normal situation.
But if I sleep PC with browser on. (The connection was on and icon was green)
After I wake the PC, the green icon is remaining even when network is disconnected yet.
Is there anyway to solve this issue?